# Backbone view top level element issue

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a view that needs to populate data to a dl tag, so I want that view to produce a markup that will look like this :

```
<dt><i class="icon-<%= icon %>"></i><%= title %></dt>
<dd><%= content %> </dd>
```

So, I don't really have a top level element that would work. It can't be a dl tag as I will need to put several item in that top element afterwards.

Is there a way out of this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no good alternative here. As you say there is no valid tag for the item view (since a `dl` is really only valid with `dt` and `dd` as children) and a view has exactly one $el.

Perhaps you should refactor your code so that you have a collection view that represents the whole DL instead? If there aren't a whole lot of models in the collection it might be OK to re-render the DL/Collection view when any of its models change:

```
var Definitions = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'dl',

  initialize: function () {
    this.collection.on('change', this.render, this);
  }

  render: function () {
    this.$el.html( <output from template that loops over all definitions> );
  }
});
```

I can't think of any way around it if you want valid HTML. If you don't care much about semantics you could use an unordered list with separate item views.

Comment: You can redraw the the pairs one-by-one if you don't mind a bit of DOM wrangling and you bind to the appropriate events. But yeah, I think you're stuck with using something other than a `<dl>` or using just one view for the whole thing. Separate sub-views for the `<dt>` and `<dd>` would be another option, I suppose it is just a question of which sort of ugly you want.

Answer (score 0):

I really dont understand too well your question, but here is an answer. As concept, a the view element should be the dl or in your case, you are defining an "item in the list" (like BookCollectionView and BookItemView) so, you could have 2 views: 1 for the  and other for an item in that list (). hope it helps you.